# Load page on select menu option being chosen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have a form like so:

```
<form>

  <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option>Today</option>
      <option>Last Week</option>
      <option>Last Month</option>
      <option>Lifetime</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

I need to do some basic filtering of results and the aim is that when a user changes the drop down the user is sent to `page/?date=THEIROPTION`

I a using the javascript on change so i dont have to have a button.

Any help?

P.S i have tried having the option value as the URL but no luck.

Comment: Please post the relevant javascript, even if it doesn't work. Show us you've made some effort.

Comment: The javascript in the <select> is what i have tried. The onchange.

The form does submit using that, but dont know what the next stage is.

Comment: nevermind, found this ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This too.

```
<form name="filter_form">
<select name="filter" onchange="document.forms.filter_form.submit();">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

**HTML:**

```
  <select onchange="loadPage(this.value)">
      <option value="page?date=today">Today</option>
      <option value="page?date=last_week">Last Week</option>
  </select>
```

**JS:**

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    location.href = url;
}
```